# Unable scale synapse pool using ADF managed identity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We are trying to create pipeline to scale up synapse pool dynamically using below documentation:
https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2021/01/scaling-azure-dedicated-sql-pools-from.html.

As per microsoft documentation Sql contributor role is required to scale database pool.Datafactory account has SQL contributor role on Azure synapse database pool but I it is throwing below error
'

```
Operation on target DW scaling activity failed: {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client '' with object id '' does not have authorization to perform action does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqlPools/write' over scope '/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/ResourcegroupName/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqldbpool_server_name/sqlPools/databasename' or the scope is invalid.
```

Any workaround or suggestion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@DAVID ALZAMENDI** suggested here [Pause and Resume Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/pause-and-resume-azure-synapse-analytics/)

Whenever you grant access to your Azure Data Factory service or Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace to control the SQL Pool, if you are using Dedicated SQL Pool **Without** Azure Synapse Workspaces, you need to select Role as **`Sql DB Contributer`**

If you are using For **Dedicated SQL Pool in Azure Synapse Workspaces**, then go to :

> **Dedicated SQL Pool >> Acess Control (IAM) >> Add >> Role as `Contributor`**